# How do I control when a contextMenuStrip is displayed?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In vb.net (2008), I want to be able to control when a contextMenuStrip (context menu) is displayed.  I don't want it to always appear when the right mouse button is clicked...only when certain criteria within my program are met.  I figure I would use addHandler but I'm not exactly clear on how to completely control the opening of the contextMenuStrip.  I know I would issue a call to the "open" method to render the contextMenuStrip.  However, I am unclear as to how to completely take over control of when to render the contextMenuStrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the control's ContextMenuStrip property to null, then handle the MouseClick event and call the ContextMenuStrip's Show function, passing the control and `e.Location`.